# How to cancel a too-broad CSS color declaration in a later stylesheet?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

In a Rails app I am using Twitter Bootstrap as a starting point. Twitter Bootstrap uses some of the HTML5 Boilerplate reset which includes this gem:

```
@media print {
    * {
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
    }
}
```

(note the linked article is from 200-effing-8)

My app outputs PDF using pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf and due to the above declaration all pdf output is black on white. The whole point of pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf (to me, in this app) is for PDF output to match the screen.

Is there any way for me to override this declaration in my stylesheets after Bootstrap is imported? I want it to be something along the lines of "auto" but that doesn't appear to be valid.

I can, of course, comment out the line in Bootstrap, but I'd rather avoid changing the source if I can (since I'm bringing it all in via the bootstrap-sass gem). I could also tell pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf to not use "print" stylesheets, but that creates different problems.

I've tried setting it to "inherit" but functionally that isn't what I'm after, and it doesn't seem to work anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment it out in the bootstrap css. The asterisk selector is a wildcard which will set all text content to black. Otherwise you would have to write out a lot of individual CSS rules using id or class to override. If most of the text content on your site is already set to black or a dark enough color, then you don't need that CSS print rule.

Comment: This was about what I expected. Thanks for confirmation, Tom.